# How can I make sure that when I click on an icon another page appears with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help. I have an icon and I want that when I press the icon that I can go to an other page, but I get this error  `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFZrc.png)

This is mine code :

```javascript
    import React from 'react';
    import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
    import { BsFileEarmarkArrowDown } from "react-icons/bs";
    // import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import "./icon.css"
    
    const Question = () => {
        return (
            <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "Green", className: "Icon", size:"3em" }}>
               <BsFileEarmarkArrowDown />
               </IconContext.Provider>
        );
      };
      
    //   export default function Firms() {
    //     return (
    //       <Link to="/Upload.js">
    //          <Question />
    //       </Link>
    //     );
    //   }
    
      export default Question
```

Comment: wher are you call the Link ?

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory, you need to wrap the code that is navigation related with a `Router`. See https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start#quick-start-1st-example-basic-routing

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `<Link>` inside of a `<Router>` tree component.

```
<Router>
  <Switch> 
    <Route exact path="/upload">
      <Upload /> // Conditionally rendered views that may contain links pointing to different routes
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Your `<Question/>` component needs to stay inside of the `<Router>` component (as everything related to routing context).

To assign a `Link` to your question, you can do like so:

```
<Question component={Link} to="/upload"/>
```

And eventually, put it somewhere inside your `<Router>` tree. Doesn't matter at which level as long as it's enclosed within the routing context:

```
<Router>
  <Switch> 
  ....
  </Switch>
  <Question component={Link} to="/upload"/>
</Router>
```

I strongly encourage you to check the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for further insights.

Answer (score 0):

1 - `<Link to="/Upload.js">` - This is wrong, `<Link>` is not used for linking to files, it should be `<Link to="/upload">`.

2 - Setup some routes

```
<Router>
  <Switch> 
    <Route exact path="/upload">
      <Upload />     /* This component from ur upload.js file */
    </Route>
    <Route path="/firms">
      <Firms />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Document: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score -1):

Link Can't be used without Router if you want to redirect the page to uploads

if you want another React Component to load as you have written Upload.js in link path

do this

```
import Uploads from 'upload.js file path';
import React from 'react';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { BsFileEarmarkArrowDown } from "react-icons/bs";
import "./icon.css"

const Question = () => {
    return (
        <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "Green", className: "Icon", size:"3em" }}>
           <BsFileEarmarkArrowDown />
           </IconContext.Provider>
    );
  };
  
   export default function Firms() {
     return (
         <Uploads/>
         <Question />  
    );
   }

  export default Question
```

you can use Use History hooks  if you want your url to go to uploads so you can do this

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { BsFileEarmarkArrowDown } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import "./icon.css"

const Question = () => {

     let history = useHistory();

    return (
        <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "Green", className: "Icon", size:"3em" }}>
           <BsFileEarmarkArrowDown />
           </IconContext.Provider>
    );
  };
  
   export default function Firms() {
     return (
     history.push("/upload");
         <Question />  
    );
   }

  export default Question
```

Hope it helps you Thank You

Comment: Your solution is anti-react.